# Can't submit a sucessful query to create a database entry in PHP

Tags: php, html, mysql, ajax, pdo

I am creating an internal knowledge base and I am struggling to successfully create new DB entries using PHP.

To use this functionality I created several files:

  * config.php, which connects to the database;

  * post.php, which displays the post;

  * post_list.php, which displays the list of posts and allows to redirect to post.php?id=x, where x is the id of each post in the database;

  * post_handler.php, which handles each post, either create or update an entry;

  * post_controller.php, which is a Post class that has multiple functions: get a certain post by id; getAll gets all posts to display in post_list; create and update posts;

  * post_editor.php, which is an editor that gets a certain post info if I'm editing a post or a blank editor if I want to create a post.

I created manually entries in MySQL table to test the previous files and I can successfully view and edit posts, but when I try to create a new entry it gives error 500 when calling post_handler.php and I can't understand why.

For the sake of simplicity and since other functions work I will show the function to create a post in the Post class (post_controller.php):

```php
    static $dbh;
    static function create ($post) {
        $sql = "INSERT INTO mydb.Posts (title, body) values (?.?)";  
        $stmt = self::$dbh -> prepare($sql);
        if ($stmt){
            $stmt -> bindValue(1, $post["title"]);                       
            $stmt -> bindValue(2, $post["body"]);                        
            return $stmt -> execute();
        }
    }
```

Here's post handler.php:

```php
    require_once("config.php");
    require_once("post_controller.php");

    if (!empty($_POST["id"])) {
        // update
        if (Post::update($_POST)) {
            echo "Successfully updated";
        } else {
            header("HTTP/1.0 500 Internal error");
            echo "Couldn't update";
        }
    } else {
        // create
        if (Post::create($_POST)) {
            echo "Successfully created new article";
            header ("Location: index.php");

        } else {
            header("HTTP/1.0 500 Internal error");
            echo "Couldn't create new article";
        }
    }
```

Here's the AJAX script to submit the form in post_editor.php:

```php
    $id = ($_GET["id"]);
    if ($id) {
        $post = Post::get((int) $id);  
    }

    // submit the form, delegation
    $(document).on("submit", "form#form", function(event){
        event.preventDefault();
        var data = $("#form").serialize();
        $.ajax({
            url: "post_handler.php",
            data: data,
            type: "post",
            success: function (response) {
                // if the request is successful
                alert(response);
                },
            error: function (xhr) {
                // if the request is not successful
                alert(xhr.responseText);
            }
        });
    });
```

I can't figure it out why updating a post works fine but I can't create new entries using this code. When I try to submit a new post the alert text box comes out blank, while on update it prompts the correct "Successfully updated" message.

What I am doing wrong?

Thank you.

Comment: is the dot a typo? `values (?.?)`

Comment: Yes it is. I fixed it, thank you! Now it works fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
"INSERT INTO mydb.Posts (title, body) values (?.?)";
```

Yes replace dot(.) with comma (,) and the code will work properly.

Comment: Thank you so much! I can't believe I let that mistake pass. You're a lifesaver, was driving crazy.